# Callback function and best practice

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, callback

**UPDATE:** I phrased the question wrong. Both the inner and outer Latitude/Longitude members need to update each other resulting in recursion. The outer members get updated by a database context while the inner ones get updated by the UI. So any changes from the database have to be propagated to the UI and vice versa. The Coordinates class CANNOT be separated from the UI and the outer members cannot be separated from the database.

I guess a flag to prevent recursion would be the simplest way around this.

I have the the following classes:

```
class Coordinates
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }

    public double CoordinateLatitude
    {
        get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
        set { /* This member needs to get updated every time Location.Coordinates.Latitude gets updated. */ }
    }

    public double CoordinateLongitude
    {
        get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
        set { /* This member needs to get updated every time Location.Coordinates.Latitude gets updated. */ }
    }
}
```

The members `CoordinateLatitude` and `CoordinateLongitude` map to the Coordinates class. What I want to achieve is the reverse as well. So when the `Coordinates` class gets updated, the members of the `Location` class should also be updated. Don't ask me why the code is structured as such because I am not at liberty to change it at the moment.

There is a LOT of code throughout the project that sets the members of the Coordinates class: `location.Coordinates.Latitude = 10.0D;`, etc. Since the `Coordinates` class (and many others) are lightweight data structures, and are used carelessly in many places, I do not want to tie them up to events.

My question is, how can I have the Location.Coordinates member update the Location.CoordinateLatitude values? Is there a standard way to set up such a callback without requiring `IDisposable` to cleanup (as in the case with events)?

Comment: Sounds like you need a property event listener, even if you dont want events..

Comment: It seems like this already does what you are asking...

Comment: If you wire up the `set` methods the same basic way you have the `get` methods, it should do what you want, no?  No callbacks needed.  Think of your public properties `CoordinateLatitude` and `CoordinateLongitude` as aliases for the corresponding properties of the `Coordinates` member.

Comment: What makes you think it is not updated.  Try myLoc.Coordinates.Latitude = 10; Debug.WriteLine myLoc.CoordinateLatitude.ToString();

Comment: The set methods of both 'Latitude' members (inner and outer) need to update each other. The outer will be updated by the database while the inner will be updated by the UI. I guess preventing recursion should do the trick.

Comment: Please demonstrate where you get recursion?  And what do you mean by callback function?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: As long as you are calling the Lat/Long getter/setter on a copy of the `Coordinates` you have in your instance of `Location`, they will be updating the same memory so they will stay in sync (barring random threading issues if you are trying to multithread as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But CoordinateLatitude does get updated
I tested your code

```
Location myLoc = new Location();
myLoc.Coordinates = new Coordinates();
myLoc.Coordinates.Latitude = 10;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLoc.CoordinateLatitude.ToString());
myLoc.Coordinates.Latitude = 20;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLoc.CoordinateLatitude.ToString());
```

Possibly what you mean to ask is why the UI does not update

It is not at all clear which is inner and which is outter and where you are getting rerecursion.
They don't (well should't) update each other.
They both just reference the same object.

This works for me.

```
class Coordinates
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

class Location : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
    public Coordinates Coordinates 
    {
        get { return coordinates; }
        set
        {
            if (coordinates == value) return;
            coordinates = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Coordinates");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CoordinateLatitude");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CoordinateLongitude");
        }
    }

    public double CoordinateLatitude
    {
        get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
        set { this.Coordinates.Latitude = value; }
    }

    public double CoordinateLongitude
    {
        get { return (this.Coordinates.Longitude); }
        set { this.Coordinates.Longitude = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code:

```
public double CoordinateLatitude
    {
        get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
        set { /* This member needs to get updated every time Location.Coordinates.Latitude gets updated. */ }
    }

    public double CoordinateLongitude
    {
        get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
        set { /* This member needs to get updated every time Location.Coordinates.Latitude gets updated. */ }
    }
```

Change `Latitude` in `CoordinateLongitude` to `Longitude`. Also, I wouldn't recommend you store these separately. Since they typically correspond to a point requiring both latitude and longitude for a coordinate, it doesn't make sense to store them independently. This would require just one call and you can eliminate `CoordinateLatitude/Longitude` altogether.

That being said, all you have to do is add these setters:

`set { this.Coordinates.Latitude = value; }`

and

`set { this.Coordinates.Longitude = value; }`

Answer (score 0):

`Coordinates` is a class so if you change it, any variable that is using that same instance is updated automaticly. Assuming I'm understanding what you want done correctly, your sets can just be:

```
public double CoordinateLatitude
{
    get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
    set { this.Coordinates.Latitude = value; }
}

public double CoordinateLongitude
{
    get { return (this.Coordinates.Longitude); }
    set { this.Coordinates.Longitude = value;  }
}
```

Edit: This would need to be done differently if `Coordinates` were a struct. This is due to the fact that `this.Coordinates` retreives a copy in that case.

```
public double CoordinateLongitude
{
    get { return (this.Coordinates.Longitude); }
    set {
        Coordinate temp = this.Coordinates;
        temp.Longitude = value;
        this.Coordinates = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Coordinates` is already a property of `Location` that your reading from in `CoordinateLatitude`, you already have it done. A read from `Location.Coordinate.Latitude` is the same as reading from `Location.CoordinateLatitude`.

```
public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }

public double CoordinateLatitude
{
  get { return (this.Coordinates.Latitude); }
  set { this.Coordinates.Latitude = value;}
}
```

In your setter you can update it to set the `Location.Coordinate.Latitude` value or just delete the setting to make it a readonly property.